# How come command line isn't recognizing this java command?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath

I enter `java -classpath C:\blahblahblah\software_engineering\cs2.jar` as part of a suggestion here: [Why does my IDE find the JAR but my command line doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842124/why-does-my-ide-find-the-jar-but-my-command-line-doesnt/14842158#comment20799927_14842158) .

I'm pretty sure this is a valid command, but I instead receive this tired list:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                    see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
```

How come?

Comment: You didn't tell java what java file to run you only gave it a classpath.

Comment: Have you read the first four lines of this tired list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving it a classpath, but not the name of the class to execute. You're also *only* including the jar file on your classpath - not the directory containing your class file.

So to repeat my answer from the other question:

```
java -cp .;cs2.jar CB
```

(Run from the directory containing both `CB.class` and `cs2.jar`.)

Comment: I kept thinking the semicolon was delimiting two separate commands.  My apologies.  And thank you.